# How to find the limit of this function with sqrt root 3?

Tags: calculus

How do we solve this? I am stuck because of sqrt root to the power of 3

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/3}-1}{x}$$

Thsnk you for helping!

Comment: Hint: $x \mapsto u-1$ and then $u \mapsto v^{\frac13}$

Comment: What do you mean by sqrt 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty standard technique.  Use the identity $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$ to simplify the numerator:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/3}-1}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/3}-1}{x}\cdot \frac{(1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1}{(1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)-1}{x((1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1)} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x((1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1)} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{(1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1} \\ &= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} 1}{\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+x)^{2/3}+(1+x)^{1/3}+1)} \\ &= \frac 13\end{align}$$

Comment: Maybe it will be more convenient to directly substitute $u=(1+x)^{1/3}$? It converts to $\lim_{u\to 1}{\frac{u-1}{u^3-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a variation rate for the function $\;u^{\tfrac13}$ aat $u=1$, hence it is
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/3}-1}{x}=\frac13u^{-\tfrac23}\Biggr\rvert_{u=1}=\frac13.$$